# MySQL - Selecting data from another table for a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following MySQL query (failed attempt):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, id, userID, total 
 FROM table1 total, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
 WHERE id = 318467989655781389 && mydb.table2.colm = 'false' 
 ORDER BY total DESC) a 
LIMIT 10
```

However, I get an error saying that `mydb.table2.colm` isn't in the field list. How can I get data from another table to use in a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: By joining it to your main table

Comment: What is the relations between the two tables? You probably need some type of `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `JOIN`.  The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT (@rownum := @rownum + 1) as rank, t1.id, t1.userID, t1.total 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     mydb.table2 t2
     ON t1.? = t2.? CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rownum := 0) params
WHERE t1.id = 318467989655781389 AND t1.colm = 'false' 
ORDER BY t1.total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The `?` is for the columns used for joining the tables together.

Notes:

- Use table aliases and qualified column names whenever a query contains more than one table.
- You can only reference a table that has been specific in the `FROM` clause.
- A subquery is not needed for the `LIMIT`.  In some versions of MySQL, a subquery might be necessary for the `ORDER BY`, but the query would look different.
- The boolean `AND` operator in SQL is `AND`.  Although `&&` works in MySQL, you might as well use the standard operator.

Comment: Oh looks like I just need to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN`. Thanks so much!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Im using version 5.7

Comment: @USER . . . It definitely supports `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Oh thats odd. Either way, `INNER JOIN` did what I needed :)